# RowFilter using Dates VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, date, datagridview, filter

I have this dates into my DGV:

```
14/06/2012
15/07/2012
16/07/2012
17/07/2012
```

I set the Filter to this: `([supplier_invoice_date] >= '13/07/2012') AND ([supplier_invoice_date] <= '17/07/2012')`

The Filter return this *(All the dates)*:

```
14/06/2012
15/07/2012
16/07/2012
17/07/2012
```

**Another test:**

Filter: `([supplier_invoice_date] >= '15/07/2012') AND ([supplier_invoice_date] <= '17/07/2012')`

Result:

```
    15/07/2012
    16/07/2012
    17/07/2012
```

Filter: `([supplier_invoice_date] < '17/06/2012')`

Result:

```
14/06/2012
15/07/2012
16/07/2012
```

I think it is only taking the days and does not take months.

Here is my code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim suppliersinvoices_data_query As String = ("DATE_FORMAT(MIN(supplier_invoice_date), '%d/%m/%Y') AS supplier_invoice_date, ...")
Dim invoice_objDataAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(suppliersinvoices_data_query, objConn)
invoice_objDataAdapter.Fill(dt)

Dim MyFilter As New DataView(dt)
MyFilter.RowFilter = "([supplier_invoice_date] >= '13/07/2012') AND ([supplier_invoice_date] <= '17/07/2012')"
invoicesresults_datagrid_search_supplierinvoice.DataSource = MyFilter
```

Comment: I think you need to convert the string to date/time

Comment: @roymustang86, can you let me some example to try? Thanks

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Comment: @roymustang86, Yup of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `DataView.RowFilter` syntax `for` Dates:

```
dataView.RowFilter = "supplier_invoice_date >= #2012-07-13#"
```

But you could also using `Linq-To-DataSet`. I assume that the actual datatype of the field is`String`instead of `Date`, so you need to parse it to `Date` first:

```
Dim startDate = New Date(2012, 7, 13)
Dim endDate =   New Date(2012, 7, 17)
Dim invoiceDate As Date
Dim filtered = From row In dt.AsEnumerable()
    Where Date.TryParse(row.Field(Of String)("supplier_invoice_date"), invoiceDate) _
    AndAlso invoiceDate >= startDate AndAlso invoiceDate <= endDate
Dim tblFiltered As DataTable = filtered.CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: I get this error:The specified conversion is not valid. look this please: http://i49.tinypic.com/28a2moj.png

Comment: I used a translator of C# to VB.NET

Comment: @JohnNuñez: Sorry, i didn't mention the VB.N ET tag, will edit soon. The reason for the exception is that the field in the DataRow is not a Date but (i assume) a String. The you need to parse it to a Date first.

Comment: I estimate enormously your help, it will wait for the edition of your response, Thanks

Comment: @JohnNuñez: Edited my answer acccordingly. Now it should work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but the example I worked to perfection thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are converting the dates to strings in order to format them.  Try to avoid that, and just let the grid use the date value it is getting from the data source.

If you want to format the date of the DataGridView control, try it like this:

```
dgv1.Columns("YourDateColumn").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Then you can use real dates to filter the data:

```
MyFilter.Filter = String.Format("[supplier_invoice_date] > '{0}'", _
                                New DateTime(2012, 7, 1))
```